# How can I change width of all Th and td using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to assign 130 to first th and first td of all rows, 100 to second th and second td of all rows, 40 to third th and third td of all rows, 120 to fourth th and fourth td of all rows and 230 to to fifth th and fifth td of all rows.

My Code for just first th and first td is

```
$('#tiptip_content table th, td').eq(0).css('width','130px');
$('#tiptip_content table th, td').eq(1).css('width','100px');
```

My dynamic HTML code is

```
<div style="display: none; margin: 624px 0px 0px 494px;" id="tiptip_holder" class="tip_top">
<div id="tiptip_arrow" style="margin-left: 313px; margin-top: 71px;">
    <div id="tiptip_arrow_inner">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tiptip_content">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 25px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;" class="xhdr">
        <img style="display: none; position: absolute;" src="https://www.lifemark.ca/contents/dhx/grid/imgs/sort_desc.gif">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; margin-right: 20px; padding-right: 20px;" class="hdr">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height: auto;">
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
                        <div class="hdrcell">
                            Ax Name
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
                        <div class="hdrcell">
                            Claimant
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
                        <div class="hdrcell">
                            Status
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
                        <div class="hdrcell">
                            Coordination Times
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
                        <div class="hdrcell">
                            Ax Address
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;" class="objbox">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" class="obj">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height: auto;">
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                    <th style="height: 0px;">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class=" ev_dhx_skyblue">
                    <td valign="middle" align="left">
                        Chiropractic Assessment
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="left">
                        Test David
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="left">
                        Booked
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="left">
                        07:30 PM - 08:30 PM;08:30 PM - 09:30 PM;09:30 PM - 10:30 PM
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="left">
                        2 Wellington Street West, Brampton, Ontario, L6Y 4R2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid inline Styles put it on a CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding any styling in a script is bad practice. They override stylesheets and it's a nightmare for future maintenance. I advice you either assign classes to these elements with their respective widths in a stylesheet, or [use css pseudo classes](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/) in a stylesheet.

```
tr > th, tr > td {
   width: 130px;
}
tr:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) {
   width: 100px;
}
tr:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {
   width: 40px;
}
tr:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) {
   width: 120px;
}
tr:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) {
   width: 230px;
}
```

Even if you *do* need to change the style dynamically, you shouldn't style in a script. You assign a class dynamically to the element and do the styling in css. Example:

```
/* add the class in the .js file */ 
$('tr:first-child').addClass('first-row');
```

And that class would look like

```
/* style the class in the .css file */
.first-row { 
  width: 130px;
}
```

Trust me, it wouldn't be the first plugin that requires a separate css file for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use classes and CSS instead of using jquery.

Give each TH a proper class like "name", "address", "date" etc.

Then just style those classes in your CSS file. You only need to give a width to the TH, the TDs will be the same.

```
th.name {width: 100px}
th.address {width: 150px}
... and so on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your question and of why you want to do this with jQuery, but you might want something like this :

```
$('#tiptip_content table tr').each(function(){
    $('th, td', this).css(function(i){
       return {width: [130, 100, 40, 120][i]}
    });
});
```

If you don't have a special reason to change all the rows, just use

```
$('#tiptip_content table tr:eq(0) th').css(function(i){
    return {width: [130, 100, 40, 120][i]}
});
```

Comment: I am using a Jquery plugin. I can't change HTML.

Comment: Yes, but why not simply change the row having all the TH and let the other rows adapt ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `nth-child`:

```
$('#tiptip_content table th:nth-child(3)') // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `table-layout:fixed`, you should be using a `<colgroup>` to define the sizes. The following should be immediate after `<table...>` and before `<tbody>`:

```
<colgroup>
    <col style="width:130px;" />
    <col style="width:100px;" />
    <col style="width:40px;" />
    <col style="width:120px;" />
    <col style="width:230px;" />
</colgroup>
```